# Switch Row/Column for Ag-Grid charts

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I'm new to web development and want to use an integrated line chart on [this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZxVr.png). The problem I have though is that the chart uses the columns as the series by default, when instead I want each row to be a series. Is it possible to switch this behavior to be more like [this in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRxSS.png)?

Comment: We'll be better able to help you if you post your code here or even better if you post it on Plunkr/JsFiddle/codesandbox etc and post the link here

Comment: I've created a small demo on codesandbox here (https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-chart-example-in2q0) adapted from the range chart example in the grid documentation to demonstrate the issue. The column headings (i.e. dates) are automatically used for the series with each row (i.e. athletes) as the categories on the x-axis. I would like to swap these.

Comment: I think you will have to find a way to transpose the array and then use the athlete names as the `field` in `colDef`. This would be more of a javascript question than an ag-grid question

Comment: I've managed to do this with a standalone chart, I wanted to check if there was some inbuilt way to do that for an integrated chart because it would be much simpler.